# Random bouncing ball

Tags: java, algorithm, bounce

I found some answers in internet which explain how to make a ball bouncing, but some of them don't helped me (because bounces are not random), and some are very difficult (my knowledge in physics are limited).

**Problem** : I have a ball which move and bounce, but not randomly, and I want to make this ball bouncing randomly.

I already have this piece of code :

```
Public Class Ball{

    /** Coordinates */
    private int x, y;

    /** Speed of the ball*/
    private int speedX, speedY;

    public Ball(int x, int y, int speedX, int speedY) {
        this.x = x ;
        this.y = y ;
        this.speedX = speedX;
        this.speedY = speedY;
    }

    public void moveAndBounce() {
        x += speedX ;
        y += speedY ;

        // Assuming that touchWallHorizontal() and touchWallHorizontal() work
        if (touchHorizontalWall()) {
            speedX = -speedX ;
        }
        if (touchVerticalWall()) {
            speedY = -speedY ;
        }
    }

    public static void main (String [] args){
        Ball ball = new Ball(); // Initialisation
        while (true){
            ball.moveAndBounce() ;
        }
    }
}
```

It works perfectly, but the ball movement is always the same (a rectangle).

**Question** : is there a way to have a random bouncing without add attributes to the ball (just with coordinates and speed) ?

And if not, is there not too difficult solution to resolve this problem ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why not just set `speedX`/`speedY` to random numbers when you need to bounce? But that only works if you don't care how fast it's going. If you need to ensure a constant velocity but need random direction, generate a random angle and calculate the speeds from that.

Comment: I tried to do `setSpeedX((int) Math.random() * 10)`. But the ball just disapear and don't bounce. I think random number can't work because the new speed need to be controlled to stay "inside" the map. But I will try to work with angles, thank you for your answer.

Comment: I should have mentioned that problem in my first comment. Random number can work. If the current speed is positive, make the random number negative; if the current speed is negative, make the random number positive. You'll run into the same issue with the random angles. Another problem, depending on how you're checking for collision with the walls, is if the speed is too high the ball will go right past it. You might try checking if the ball is outside the box, and if it is, move it back so it is just inside the box.

Comment: please post that solution as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Here is the new code for moveAndBounce() method (Thanks to johnHopkins) :

```
public void moveAndBounce() {
    x += speedX ;
    y += speedY ;

    Random random = new Random();
    if (touchHorizontalWall()) {
        if (speedX > 0) {

            // New speed between 10 and 15 (you can choose other)
            setSpeedX(-random.nextInt(15) + 10);
        } else {
            setSpeedX(random.nextInt(15) + 10
        }
    }
    if (touchVerticalWall()) {
        if (speedY > 0) {
            setSpeedY(-random.nextInt(15) + 10);
        } else {
            setSpeedY(random.nextInt(15) + 10);
        }
    }
}
```